# Looking for a jquery plugin to serialize a form to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery function or plugin that serializes form inputs to an object using the naming convention for deep-serialization supported by [param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) in jQuery 1.4:

```
<form>
  <input name="a[b]" value="1"/>
  <input name="a[c]" value="2"/>
  <input name="d[]" value="3"/>
  <input name="d[]" value="4"/>
  <input name="d[2][e]" value="5"/>
</form>

$('form').serializeObject(); // { a: { b:"1",c:"2" }, d: ["3","4",{ e:"5" }] }
```

Prototype's [Form.serialize](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/serialize/) method can do exactly this. What's the jQuery equivalent? I found [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject) but it doesn't follow this naming convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there didn't seem to be any existing libraries that accomplished what I was seeking, I mashed up bits from a couple of existing libraries that did similar things:

- The jQuery.deparam function from [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)
- The jQuery.serializeObject function mentioned in the question.

Both are by [Ben Alman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142339/cowboy-ben-alman). Thanks, Ben!

The result: http://gist.github.com/405448

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery form plugin. I haven't tested it, but I think it will fix your problem

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: I don't see anything in the [API](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) that does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need pluging.

$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).serializeArray());
  return false;
});

look at
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: serializeArray does not do what I asked; it would produce [{name: "a[b]", value: "1"}, {name: "a[c]", value: "2"}, ...].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but there's a jQuery plugin thad does what you need.

http://v3.javascriptmvc.com/index.html#&who=jQuery.fn.formParams